# Dont execute jQuery unless all form fields have been completed

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a very large form consisting of about 40 questions. I've split the questions into sections, 10 in each one and each is wrapped in a div.

I'm using jQuery to slide the divs in and out

```
 $('a.nextform').click(function(e){  
       $('.hold-all').animate({"left": "-=690"}, 500);
        e.preventDefault();
    })
 $('a.backform').click(function(e){  
       $('.hold-all').animate({"left": "+=690"}, 500);
       e.preventDefault();
    })
```

I want to somehow say, if the requeired fields HAVENT been completed, dont allow the user to click next, is this possible with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

give inputs an id, for example `<input id='name' type='text'/>`

Then check if its empty using

`$('#name').val()`

example

```
if($('#name').val() != ''){
//do
}
else
{
//dont do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the attribute disabled="disabled" on the button input with JQuery: [see w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp) e.g. `$(button).attr('disabled', 'disabled')`. You can also put a handler on `$(form).submit` and preventDefault and return false. You can also do `return false` on your click handlers above to prevent any more click code from executing.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to break down the validation into stages too, i.e. don't move to the next div until the inputs are all validated on the current div.

There are various plugins for form validation for jquery which you can use, you might start with http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation.

Then you can use the .valid() to check whether to move on or to show an error, a quick rough example:

```
$('a.nextform').click(function(e){ 
if ("#myform").valid()) {
$('.hold-all').animate({"left": "-=690"}, 500);
    e.preventDefault();
}
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course.  Iterate through each of the input fields - you could group them by using a fieldset and use something like .children('input, textarea') - inspect each of the inputs and verify whether there is a value for the given input.

Answer (score 0):

It would be crazy and difficult to maintain if you write this manually for all the form fields.  Adding or removing fields to the list would soon make the process difficult to maintain, manage and keep track of.

The problem you face is a common one and also a solved one: 'Validation'

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Basically add a css class 'required' to any field that is mandatory.  Call run the validation plugin on your form, or a container of the form.

When the user clicks Next call $("form#questions").validate()

If validate returns true, slide the next div in.  If it returns false don't. The validate plugin can also add a validation message to the end of the field that has failed validation, and/or provide a validation summary message of the failed constraints: see documentation for more details.

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

Comment: My only concern @reach4thelasers is that there are more required forms that are display:none that are meant to appear after the first div forms are all completem would the plugin not see these as empty and not run?

Comment: Just validate each one individually, run the validate plugin seperately on the form/container for each subsection, and call validate() from the next button handler on each one.  $("#form1").validate() $("#form2").validate()